# Can a duplicate post with a bounty be marked as a duplicate

Tags: support

For instance, if I start a bounty on a question and someone decides to mark it as a duplicate, are they able to do so? Or can bounty questions not be marked as a duplicate until the bounty on it has expired?

If they are able to mark it as a duplicate, would I get my reputation back which I spent on the bounty or not?

Comment: Questions with bounties cannot be closed until the bounty is over. Granted, you can't start a bounty for two days after you post the question, so if your question is an obvious duplicate on an active tag, it'll likely be close before you can bounty it.

Comment: @Kendra I took a look at that, however I wondered whether different circumstances applied for a question being closed or marked as a duplicate

Comment: The answer says bountied questions can't be closed. Duplicate is really just another kind of closure, so why would it be special?